# How to set tooltip position just beneath the cursor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to show the tooltip just *beneath* the cursor position, and not in its default position (its show the tooltip behind the cursor). How can I set its position?

I did nothing, but added a tooltip in the form and wrote the following code to display it on button hover:

`toolTip1.Show("Text", button1);`

Answer (score 4):

Use this overload of the [`ToolTip.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.Show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
public void Show(
    string text,
    IWin32Window window,
    Point point
)
```

Your code then becomes:

```
Point pos = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - 1); //Change this to whatever you want
toolTip1.Show("Text", button1, pos);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i actually need 1 solution to set all toolTips positions to always start from beneath the cursor. I am sure, there will be a solution for that.

Comment: Please [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode(v=vs.110).aspx).